# Converting the result of NumberFormat.parse() into a BigDecimal

Tags: kotlin, number-formatting

I've defined a `formatter` like so:

```
>>> import java.text.NumberFormat
>>> val formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance()
```

It would appear that the result of `formatter.parse("1,000")` is a [`Long`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-long/index.html):

```
>>> formatter.parse("1,000")::class
class kotlin.Long
```

However, if I try to pass it to the constructor of `BigDecimal`, I get an error message saying that it doesn't match any of the constructors:

```
>>> BigDecimal(formatter.parse("1,000"))
error: none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public constructor BigDecimal(p0: BigInteger!) defined in java.math.BigDecimal
public constructor BigDecimal(p0: CharArray!) defined in java.math.BigDecimal
public constructor BigDecimal(p0: Double) defined in java.math.BigDecimal
public constructor BigDecimal(p0: Int) defined in java.math.BigDecimal
public constructor BigDecimal(p0: Long) defined in java.math.BigDecimal
public constructor BigDecimal(p0: String!) defined in java.math.BigDecimal
BigDecimal(formatter.parse("1,000"))
^
```

This is despite that

```
>>> formatter.parse("1,000") == 1000L
true
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `parse()` returns `Number` at compile time. There's no matching constructor overload.

Comment: Is there any other way to get a `BigDecimal` out of the result of `formatter.parse()`?

Comment: You can call `Number.longValue()` if you're sure it'll always be a long. Or you can use `DecimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In kotlin

```
 formatter.parse("1,000") //this result in not Long.Its is Number
```

so you have to convert as Long

```
fun main()
{
val formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance()
val result:Number=formatter.parse("1,000")
val decimal=BigDecimal(result.toLong())
println(decimal) //out put is 1000

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your value to Long before passing it to the `BigDecimal` constructor, since it is a `Number`. You can either use `.toLong()` or create an extension function for `Number` which returns BigDecimal:

`fun Number.bigDecimialValue(): BigDecimal = BigDecimal(this.toLong())`